# cannot access project Resources from apk/res-auto namespace

Tags: android, xamarin, namespaces, resources, visual-studio-2017

i'm getting a couple errors here which make no sense to me:

here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ToolbarLayout">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/Toolbar" android:layout="@layout/Toolbar"/><!-- AVAILABLE HERE --><!-- app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"-->
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ContentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ToolbarLayout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/NavView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        app:headerLayout="@layout/Toolbar"
        app:menu="@menu/Toolbar" />       <!-- NOT AVAILABLE HERE -->
        <!--app:headerLayout="@layout/NavHeader"
        app:menu="@menu/NavMenu"
          android:layout_gravity="start"-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and here's the error list:

[image: Errors]
As you can see the Toolbar clearly exists as it is referenced in the include tag, however isn't available in the two properties which use the app namespace.

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resources cannot have capital letters in their names.  so in this case I needed to change my Toolbar.axml to toolbar.axml

resource found in xamarins ticketing system at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36821